# Libgdx : sliding an actor out of stage bounds with Action MoveTo()

Tags: libgdx, stage, scene2d

I am using a Scene2D action to add a slide moving effect to an actor in my stage.

```
Window w = new Window(mytitle, myskin);
w.setPosition(stage.getWidth()/2 - w.getWidth()/2, 0);
w.addAction(moveTo(stage.getWidth()+w.getWidth(), 0, 1));
stage.addActor(w);
```

My goal is to move this window from the x-center of the stage to the right bound of the stage PLUS the window's width.

So far this code only makes the window move from the x-center of the stage to the right bound of the stage MINUS the window's width.

To explain it graphically:
[image]

So how can I use a MoveTo Action to move an actor BEYOND the bounds of the stage?

I guess I could artificially create a stage bigger than what I display on screen but that sounds like solving a problem with additional problems.

Thanks for your time

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem to move an actor out of the stage. Just tried that and my actor flies out of the screen. Maybe show some more of the code to be able to figure out what happens. Or maybe try using  moveBy instead: `moveBy(stage.getWidth()/2 + w.getWidth()/2, 0, 1f);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer donfuxx, unfortunately changing to MoveBy doesn't change anything. Does your actor flies out of the screen with the code you have written?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:
window.setKeepWithinStage(false);

Here is the full post:
[libgdx position window outside of stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021238/libgdx-position-window-outside-of-stage)